# Is an ongoing Human Occupied Landfill (HōL) campaign possible?

Tags: campaign-development, human-occupied-landfill

Back when White Wolf ruled the land of RPGs, they released a really bizarre game called [HōL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Occupied_Landfill) on their Black Dog label.  A lot of the game was obviously written as a joke, but I've felt myself drawn back to it over and over.  It looked ridiculous, over-the-top, and just like a lot of fun.  It reminded me of Paranoia.  Now, I always thought Paranoia was a lot of fun, but it also never seemed possible to play a continuous campaign of Paranoia, just single-shot games.  Is that true of HoL?

Has anyone run an ongoing Human Occupied Landfill campaign, or formed a strong opinion on why it is or isn't possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We did run an excellent mini-campaign in HoL. I think our key was keeping the humor level in check, not losing a certain "realism" and focusing more on the game (that is, our group) parodying other settings and rpgs in its ironic, somewhat sour way than on mindless and continuous joking.

I'd suggest going for a humor / story / realism ratio found in the novels of Terry Pratchett and Douglas Adams - and not to lose heart if/when there's nothing funny about certain scenes or even sessions. Don't force humor, but don't let its excess ruin the game either. And do use a lot of twisted references to worlds etc that you and your group like.

Answer (score 5):

Having known several who have run ongoing campaigns of *Hōl*, yes it's possible.

It can even be done in a more serious tone, if your players can handle the depression-factor of life in the dumps.

(Even I have shudders at that pun I just made.)

The rules are fairly brutal. The game is darkly humorous.

*Buttery Hōlsomeness* adds more material for more options in play.

Answer (score 3):

HoL is perfectly playable as an ongoing campaign. It is one of my favorite all time inspirations in roleplaying, if in nothing else, how bizarre sourcebooks can be. There is a certain dystopian nuance to HoL that can be woven into other systems and campaigns.

They can go two ways, one is light hearted, the other is very, very grim.

I second the suggestion to pick up Buttery HoLsomeness, it has the character generation rules for HoL.

All in all a great game, might try something with a dual campaign in the vein of The Maxx, where one takes place in a 'real world' and the imaginary one set on HoL, had a lot of fun with that….

Yes, you can make a long term campaign out of HoL.